# React hook form typescript types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

Hi I'm using react hook form to create a dynamic field, also I'm using use field array.
When i try to access errors for these dynamic fields, I'm getting the following type error.

[image: screenshot of the current code]

I'm using `Controller` and the name for the current field I'm rendering is `name={`services[${index}].value `as any}`

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `Controller` component and need to access the error list of your fields array you can specify the type of your field values in the Controller like this:

*Assuming the type of your fields is called `FieldValues` and we render a custom component called Input.*

```
<Controller<FieldValues>
  name={`services.${index}.value`}
  render={({ field, formState: { errors } }): ReactElement => (
    <div>
      <Input {...field} />
      {errors.services?.[index]?.message && <p>{errors.services[index]?.message}</p>}
    </div>
  )}
/>
```

This way, Typescript will correctly understand the structure of your form field names.

You can also immediately access the error of the specific field with the `fieldState`, so no explicit specification of types would be necessary.

```
<Controller
  name="your-field-name"
  render={({ field, fieldState: { error } }): ReactElement => (
    <div>
      <Input {...field} />
      {error && <p>{error.message}</p>}
    </div>
  )}
/>
```

On the other hand, if you are using the `useController` hook you can also pass the type of your form with its generic, `useController<FieldValues>`.

As I commented initially, these examples are based on a form of the type:

```
type FieldValues = { services: { value: string }[] };
```

These are basic examples but I hope they are useful to understand the different ways to identify the names of your fields correctly with Typescript.